# why when i select all data is showing but when i use find or where data not showing even if i check with dd

Tags: laravel

some make me confusing in laravel when i use all() data is showing but when i select find or where data not showing when i use dd function in laravel

```
//$regency = Regency::find(1101);
//$regency = Regency::where('number','=',$prov_id);
        $regency = DB::table('regencies')->where('province_id', $prov_id);
        dd($regency);
```

i try use eloquent and query builder but still same result.
[those is result in dd if i using query builder, but why when i use select all data is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plU7i.png)

Answer (score 1):

What you are showing is the `Query Builder` you need to execute it with `->get()` to get the Collection.